# envsubst works only for part of the variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, envsubst

I have a file with some $VARIABLES which I want to substitute using envsubst tool. But in my case the tool is substituting only +/- half of the variables.

To illustrate:
I have a file **.env** with some variables:

```
MODE=HTTP
URL=https://some.url:0000/xyz
```

I use

```
$ source .env
```

And now, when both of the variables are set only MODE is correctly used by envsubst

```
echo $MODE 
HTTP
echo 'mode: $MODE' | envsubst
mode: HTTP


echo $URL
https://some.url:0000/xyz
echo 'url: $URL' | envsubst
url:
```

Any ideas why envsubst not working for all variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that it's only working for `$MODE` by accident - because you have an exported `$MODE` variable in your shell.

In order for `envsubst` to work it needs to inherit the environment variables from your shell which is only done for `export`ed variables.

It'll work if your `.env` file exports the variables:

```sh
MODE=HTTP
URL=https://some.url:0000/xyz

export MODE
export URL
```

Comment: that's right. I exported variables and now its working :)